# Why do I keep getting the error "Unable to locate package gadmin-proftpd"

Tags: apt, 20.04

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I'm quite new to it.
I've been trying to install gadmin-proftpd with the following command
`$ sudo apt-get install gadmin-proftpd`
but I keep getting the error
`E: Unable to locate package gadmin-proftpd`

I already enabled **Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)** in Software & Updates. I've also tried `sudo apt-get update`
I don't seem to be able to find anyone else having the same issue online.
Please shed some light on my issue if you can. I am still really new to linux.

Comment: This package exists only for focal,  for jammy it's simply not in the repository. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gadmin-proftpd&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-on-ubuntu/

Comment: The `gadmin-proftpd` package was removed from Ubuntu after 20.04. It is not available in 22.04. You can see this clearly for yourself at https://packages.ubuntu.com